# Cant added flutter onPress

Tags: flutter

I'm beginner to flutter , I tried to added my flutter **Press** navigation code to  'accountWidget' ,  but its cant be added on this anyone know how to do that correctly

Thanks
my code here

```
 press: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return HomePage();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
```

**Account.dart**

```
  Widget _accountWidget() {

    return Container(


        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: accounts.length,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 18, bottom: 29),

              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 76,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 13),
                  padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, top: 12, bottom: 12, right: 22),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: kWhiteColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: kTenBlackColor,
                        blurRadius: 10,
                        spreadRadius: 5,
                        offset: Offset(8.0, 8.0),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),

                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 57,
                            width: 57,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(accounts[index].photo),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),


                          SizedBox(
                            width: 13,
                          ),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

                            children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top:15.0),
                            child: Center(
                              child:   Text(
                                accounts[index].name,
                                style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    color: kBlackColor),
                              ),
                              
                            ),
                          ),
                              Text(
                                accounts[index].version,
                                style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    color: kGreyColor),
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),

                    ],

                  ),






                );
              },
              shrinkWrap: true,


              controller: ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: false),
            )

          ],
        ),
      );

  }
```

Comment: so you want to navigate from one page to another page?

Comment: @ajay , Hello yes, I'm  not idea there is put to my code. `press: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return HomePage();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },`

Comment: you can wrap any widget with InkWell or GestureDetector (Widget that detects gestures). which has onTap → GestureTapCallback, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html. I think this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are missing a widget which has a `onPressed` or `onTap` property, none of your widgets is configured to be press-able. Easiest way to achieve this, is making use of the `GestureDetector` widget, which can listen to various kinds of gestures, including `onTap`. Just Wrap it around the part of your widget tree which should be press-able - syntax for this use case goes like:

```dart
GestureDetector(
  /// This makes sure the whole area is clickable and not only the actual widgets inside
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  /// Your press function
  onTap: press,
  /// The rest of your widget tree
  child: ...
)
```

There are quite some widgets which have interaction properties like `onPressed` on their own, like `FlatButton` or `ListTile`. I would recommend to take a look at the [Flutter widget catalog](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets) where you can see different kind of existing widgets which solve common problems like touch events, input etc.